# Should I file a nonresident state return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax

My home is in North Carolina. Last year I lived in NC from 01/01/2017 to 10/10/2017. Then I got a Subcontractor job in Pennsylvania. The definition of Subcontractor is my employer is a software consulting company in TX. They got a project in PA and then they hired developers to work for the project on site.

So I rented an apartment in Pennsylvania. The job must be onsite. Please see my pay stub.

[image: paycheck]

I believe that I should file the tax for NC. But how about PA and TX?